# What causes subsequent .form-inline

Tags: css, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to develop a tabletop character sheet in Bootstrap 3. 
In the information box pictured below, I have three inline forms. I am trying to create well defined rows (but not necessarily well defined columns)

I'm having this problem on large (alignment appears mostly fine on my tablet) screens where my third `.form-inline` sits strangely aligned below 2nd. I want each form-inline to be vertically separated (like rows), but I don't understand why the separate `form-inline` divs are not doing this.

I have provided my source and some pictures of my issue below.

**Excerpt from my main HTML file**

```css
/*********************************************************************************/

/* Custom CSS                                                                    */

/*********************************************************************************/

/ #CharHeaderLine1 > div,
#CharHeaderLine2 > div,
#CharHeaderLine3 > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
#PFCharHeader > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#PFCharHeader {
  padding: 1%;
}
#ClassesAndLevels > span,
input,
#AbilityScores,
#PFCharHeader {
  display: inline-block;
}
#sidebar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#CharHeaderInfoDiv {
  background-color: ##f2f2f2;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#CharacterSheetBody {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 1%;
}
.vcenter {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
/*
    .col-md-4
    {
     margin: 0px;
     color: #9d9d9d;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 20%;
    }
    */

.ExpandableMenu [type="checkbox"] {
  size: 50%;
}
/*********************************************************************************/

/* Copyright                                                                     */

/*********************************************************************************/

#copyright {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3em 0em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #877850;
  background: #62573b;
}
#copyright .container {} #copyright a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #877850;
}
```

```html
<div id="CharHeaderInfoDiv" class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 panel">
  <div id="CharHeaderLine1" class="form-inline">
    <div class="TextFieldClass form-group col-md-4 CharInfoField" id="CharacterNameBox">
      <label>Character Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter Character Name" />
    </div>

    <div id="AlignmentDropdownDiv" class="Dropdown Class col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
      <label>Alignment</label>
      <div id="AlignmentAxis1Selector" class="row">
        <div class="btn-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Lawful
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked>Neutral
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Chaotic
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="AlignmentAxis2Selector" class="row">
        <div class="btn-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Good
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked>Neutral
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Evil
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="CharHeaderLine2" class="form-inline">
    <div id="DeityDiv" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 form-group">
      <label>Deity</label>
      <input id="DeityField" class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter Deity" />
    </div>
    <div id="HomelandDiv" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xl-3 col-md-offset-1 form-group">
      <label>Homeland</label>
      <input id="HomelandField" class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter Homeland" />
    </div>
    <div id="RaceInfoDiv" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xl-3 form-group">
      <label>Race</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Core | Dwarf</option>
        <option>Core | Elf</option>
        <option>Core | Gnome</option>
        <option>Core | Half Elf</option>
        <option>Core | Half Orc</option>
        <option>Core | Halfling</option>
        <option>Core | Human</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="CharHeaderLine3" class="form-inline">
    <div id="SexDiv" class="col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xl-3 form-group">
      <label>Sex</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>Intersex</option>
        <option>None</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="AgeDiv" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 form-group">
      <label>Age</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="AgeYearField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Age">
        <div class="input-group-addon">years</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HeightDiv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-4">
      <label>Height</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="HeightFtField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="HeightFeet">
        <span class="input-group-addon">ft.</span>
        <input id="HeightInField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="HeightInch">
        <div class="input-group-addon">in.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="WeightDiv" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <label>Weight</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="WeightField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Weight">
        <div class="input-group-addon">lbs.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HairColorDiv" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
      <label>Hair</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="HairColorField" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Hair">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="EyeColorDiv" class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
      <label>Eyes</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="EyesColorField" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Eyes">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could be causing this issue, and why?

[image: Picture of the issue without markup][image: The issue with some markup]

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Here's the fiddle, but it doesn't seem to have the same issue: https://jsfiddle.net/vb3hnqkf/

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your problem described?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. I can't seem to replicate the issue using JSFiddle. I said in the original post: this issue is only occurring on large screens, and I can't seem to get the JSFiddle display window to a size large enough to know for certain if the issue occurs in Fiddle or not. Any tips? sorry, very new to web-dev and Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

check this html. seems working fine in large device. But Im not sure  other devices.

```
        <div id="CharHeaderInfoDiv" class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 panel">
          <div id="CharHeaderLine1" class="form-inline">
            <div class="TextFieldClass form-group col-md-4 CharInfoField" id="CharacterNameBox">
              <label>Character Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter Character Name">
            </div>

            <div id="AlignmentDropdownDiv" class="Dropdown Class col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
              <label>Alignment</label>
              <div id="AlignmentAxis1Selector" class="row">
                <div class="btn-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Lawful
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 active">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked="">Neutral
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Chaotic
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="AlignmentAxis2Selector" class="row">
                <div class="btn-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Good
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 active">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked="">Neutral
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Evil
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="CharHeaderLine2" class="form-inline">
            <div id="DeityDiv" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 form-group">
              <label>Deity</label>
              <input id="DeityField" class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter Deity">
            </div>
            <div id="HomelandDiv" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xl-3 col-md-offset-1 form-group">
              <label>Homeland</label>
              <input id="HomelandField" class="form-control" type="text" value="Enter Homeland">
            </div>
            <div id="RaceInfoDiv" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xl-3 form-group">
              <label>Race</label>
              <select class="form-control">
                <option>Core | Dwarf</option>
                <option>Core | Elf</option>
                <option>Core | Gnome</option>
                <option>Core | Half Elf</option>
                <option>Core | Half Orc</option>
                <option>Core | Halfling</option>
                <option>Core | Human</option>
                <option>Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="CharHeaderLine3" class="form-inline">
            <div id="SexDiv" class="col-md-2 col-lg-3 form-group col-xl-3">
              <label>Sex</label>
              <select class="form-control">
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
                <option>Intersex</option>
                <option>None</option>
                <option>Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div id="AgeDiv" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 form-group col-xl-3">
              <label>Age</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="AgeYearField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Age">
                <div class="input-group-addon">years</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="HeightDiv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-4">
              <label>Height</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="HeightFtField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="HeightFeet">
                <span class="input-group-addon">ft.</span>
                <input id="HeightInField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="HeightInch">
                <div class="input-group-addon">in.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="WeightDiv" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
              <label>Weight</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="WeightField" type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Weight">
                <div class="input-group-addon">lbs.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="HairColorDiv" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
              <label>Hair</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="HairColorField" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Hair">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="EyeColorDiv" class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
              <label>Eyes</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="EyesColorField" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Eyes">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you set col-lg-offset-1 for sexdiv first div. So its take space at leftside. I just removed.